# How to use XmlNode() as result from webservice in VB.NET?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode

A webservice just returns XmlNode():

```
Dim nodes() As XmlNode = CType(result.handler, XmlNode())
```

First of all, how can this result be viewed as plain xml (in visual studio)?

And then, how to use this result and navigate / select concrete items from it?

Comment: *1. how can this result be viewed as plain xml (in visual studio)?*: Do you mean like while debbuging? If you just stop the mouse pointer over the variable, you can view its contents! *2. how to use this result and navigate / select concrete items from it?*: Do you have a class that represents the contents of this result? If so, you can deserialize the XmlNode into your object, that's the easiest way, I think, otherwise you can just use the Xml library to navigate through it. Please give more information about what you really want.

Comment: 1. I don't mean the debugger in this context. It drives me crazy when viewing the nested objects ;) I would like to view the the whole xml structure like a dom document. Looking for something like $nodesArray->toXmlString()
2. There is no target class at them moment. have to use Xml library, but what to use when not having an XmlDocument but only an XmlNodes()?

Comment: Since is is an array you have to convert one item in the array at a time.  So I usually use something like this string xml = string.Join("\n", nodes.Select(x => x.ToString()));

Answer (score 0):

> **First of all, how can this result be viewed as plain xml (in visual studio)?**

You can use [`XmlNode.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.writeto#System_Xml_XmlNode_WriteTo_System_Xml_XmlWriter_) method, using a `XmlWriter` object created for writing to a `StringBuilder` object ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.create#System_Xml_XmlWriter_Create_System_Text_StringBuilder_System_Xml_XmlWriterSettings_)), for example:

```vb
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml

'[...]
Public Function NodesToString(nodes() As XmlNode) As String

   Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

   Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
   settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
   settings.Indent = True

   Dim writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
   For Each node In nodes
      node.WriteTo(writer)
   Next
   writer.Close()

   Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

After that all the contents of your nodes should be on your `StringBuilder` object, and a simple `sb.ToString()` would show it all to you.

> **And then, how to use this result and navigate / select concrete items from it?**

[`XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode) is the base class for a lot of elements in the `System.Xml` library, even [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) and [`XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement) classes, so a lot of the XML "navigation capability" is there.

As stated by the documentation:

> *This class implements the W3C Document Object Model (DOM) Level 1 Core and the Core DOM Level 2. The DOM is an in-memory (cache) tree representation of an XML document. `XmlNode` is the base class in the .NET implementation of the DOM. It supports XPath selections and provides editing capabilities. The `XmlDocument` class extends `XmlNode` and represents an XML document. You can use `XmlDocument` to load and save XML data. It also includes methods for node creation. See [XML Document Object Model (DOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-document-object-model-dom) for more information.*

You can use those properties or methods to navigate through your XML nodes, for example:

- [`XmlNode.FirstChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.firstchild) property
- [`XmlNode.NextSibling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.nextsibling) property
- [`XmlNode.CreateNavigator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.createnavigator) method
- [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes) method (using XPath expression)
- [`XmlNode.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode) method (using XPath expression)